# Generate Excel From Stream

Tags: excel, azure, optimization, stream, epplus

I would ask if the method that I occupy is the most optimal to create an excel file from streams.
I ask because this process can grow and could cause problems.

It is a recursive process.
First makes a request for data.
Create the Stream
Creates the file and saves (Azure)

Here's the important thing, if one user makes a new request reads the old file is downloaded and merge it with the new data, all in data stream certainly use the EPPlus library, the file can have 60,000 rows.

Some code:

```
//Request Data
var dta = db.Database.SqlQuery<ListData>(String.Format(......

//Generate Container - StreamData can be null or contain old data downloaded
using (ExcelPackage epck = new ExcelPackage(StreamData)){...}

foreach (var item in dta){...}
```

The function that takes more time is when the file is created (The library creates a row at a time from my list of data accessed) with the help of the library

I hope you can guide me to improve my process, or tell me some method that has helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EPPlus has few functions (below) to load all data in single step instead or looping for all the records. I have used LoadFromDataTable() and it's quick, saves lot of time.

```
LoadFromArrays()
LoadFromCollection<T>()
LoadFromDataReader()
LoadFromDataTable()
LoadFromText()
```

In addition to that, use ranges to do the formatting and other stuff instead of looping individual cells.